# Como poderia marcar um texto em formato html sem excluir o conteúdo?

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma maneira de colocar uma marcação na HTML tipo, se eu selecionar uma parte da html com o mouse, onde tiver com foco, ele escrever um texto [mark-open] e depois no final, [mark-close]:

```
<div id="container">
    <p>
    [mark->open]
    Meu texto estará aqui aberto<br>
    </p>
    <p>E ele será fechado no final com uma tag
    [mark-close]
    </p>
</div>
```

Eu sei que para abrir eu posso fazer o seguinte:

```
function getSelectedText() {
  t = (document.all) ? document.selection.createRange().text : document.getSelection();

  return t;
}

$(document).bind('mouseup','#container',function(){
    var selection = getSelectedText();
    var selection_text = selection.toString();

    var openTag = document.createTextNode('[mark->open]');

    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.insertNode(openTag);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/j1gLur92/)

Agora e para fechar? Veja que eu não quero deletar o conteúdo, e nem converter o texto selecionado para string.

[Aqui tem um exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/4yuvmk3s/221/) que precisa melhorar, na questão da busca.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function getSelectedText() {
  t = (document.all) ? document.selection.createRange().text : document.getSelection();

  return t;
}

$(document).bind('mouseup','#container',function(){
    var selection = getSelectedText();
    var selection_text = selection.toString();

    var openTag = document.createTextNode('[mark->open]');
var closeTag = document.createTextNode('[mark->close]');

    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.insertNode(openTag);
   var range2 = selection.getRangeAt(1);
    range.insertNode(closeTag);
});
```

Espero te ajudado,senão me avise .

Comment: Não funcionou, não.

Comment: você quer a tag <mark> ? Porque essa tag destacar um texto.